# Laravel Forge database seeder

Tags: laravel, forge

I'm trying to insert a user into my laravel forge site automatically, but the seeder is not working. I can create a user and log in, but I'm trying to have a default admin user once the site is live.

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'Jovani Calixte',
            'is_admin' => 1,
            'email' => 'user1@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this the database user php file

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the site to forge and try to log in I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

1. Whoops! Something went wrong.
2. These credentials do not match our
   records.

Comment: Is it exist in your database? did you run migration from forge?

Comment: yes, from my understanding $FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force  should run your migration right? if not what is the best way to run and seed database on forge side and thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, but no seeders. Check John_ch's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to seed the database on the Forge provisioned server, you can log into Forge and navigate to your server/site, and click "Commands" in the navbar on the left, you can then run the command for your seeder,

```
php artisan db:seed
```

or

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

To ensure that this data did indeed seed, you should check your users table to make sure that the record is in the table.

Comment: FYI for OP `$FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force` will run migrate only when deployment, but no seeders.